# Select distinct records if status is not null

Tags: mysql

I have a leave application table which has duplicate records.

Leave application table:

```
leave_app_id  user_id    from_date      to_date      reason       status  approved_by
    1           5        2021-08-07     2021-08-09   Sick Leave   NULL    NULL
    2           5        2021-08-07     2021-08-09   Sick Leave   NULL    NULL
    3           5        2021-08-07     2021-08-09   Sick Leave   1       9
    4           10       2021-09-02     2021-09-05   Medical      NULL    NULL
    5           10       2021-09-02     2021-09-05   Medical      NULL    NULL
```

Got distinct records by using this query:

```
SELECT
    MIN(leave_app_id) leave_app_id,
    a.user_id,
    a.from_date,
    a.to_date,
    a.reason,
    a.status,
    (SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) FROM tbl_users WHERE user_id = a.approved_by) approved_by
FROM
    tbl_leave_applications a
    INNER JOIN tbl_users u ON u.user_id = a.user_id
GROUP BY
    a.user_id,
    a.from_date,
    a.to_date,
    a.reason,
    a.status,
    a.approved_by
```

Result of above query:

```
leave_app_id  user_id    from_date      to_date      reason       status  approved_by
    1           5        2021-08-07     2021-08-09   Sick Leave   NULL    NULL
    3           5        2021-08-07     2021-08-09   Sick Leave   1       John Doe
    4           10       2021-09-02     2021-09-05   Medical      NULL    NULL
```

**However I want, if status is not null then it should display that record only.**

**Like this:**

```
leave_app_id  user_id    from_date      to_date      reason       status  approved_by
    3           5        2021-08-07     2021-08-09   Sick Leave   1       John Doe
    4           10       2021-09-02     2021-09-05   Medical      NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Append HAVING a.status NOT NULL in your query

Comment: @Sabhashis wouldn't it exclude records like `leave_app_id = 4` that glitchy wanted to see in the returned dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN a.status IS NOT NULL THEN a.leave_app_id END), MIN(a.leave_app_id)) AS leave_app_id,
    a.user_id,
    a.from_date,
    a.to_date,
    a.reason,
    MAX(a.status) AS status,
    MAX(CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name)) AS approved_by
FROL tbl_leave_applications a
INNER JOIN tbl_users u ON u.user_id = a.user_id
GROUP BY
    a.user_id,
    a.from_date,
    a.to_date,
    a.reason;
```

Comment: I guess the provided code will cause loss of records with this same `user_id`, `from_date`, `to_date` and `reason` having other (or same) not `NULL` values of `status`

Comment: @asd-tm Why would you expect that such data exists?  The OP makes no mention of this, and, if this be required, then the OP is totally lacking a proper problem statement.

Comment: I agree with you. However the author stated only one reason for excluding records from tge returned dataset. As well as the author did not state that he wanted to exclude some (possibly random) duplicates of records with not NULL `status`. However, the code must be ready for such a test.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Perfect!